# Python modularity statistic using louvain package

Tags: igraph

I am trying to do batch wise run of python's louvain modularity partition of my network atleast a 100 times. I need to save the partitions and save the modularity score after the partition.Is there any way to get both of them? I have tried the documentation and example and it only returns the partitions but no modularity statistic. Please point me to the right direction and I will be extremely grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the modularity score using `igraph.Graph.community()`:

```
import igraph

g = igraph.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n=100, p=0.1)
clusters = g.community_multilevel()
modularity_score = g.modularity(clusters.membership)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This helps. I was able to get the cluster memberships and modularity at the same time for my network. One question I have is when I run find_parition on my weighted graph and print the variable holding the partitions, I see my node labels and what cluster they are in, but when I just print variable.membership I see cluster numbers in a list.

Comment: Is there a way for me to access the data structure of my variable that holds all my node labels and what cluster they belong to. If not then can I assume the variable.memberships is in the same order as my list of nodes when I added them to the graph. I am very grateful for your concern.

Comment: Cluster assignments in `clusters.membership` are in the same order as the nodes in `igraph.Graph.vs`(in the example `g.vs`), which in turn should be the order in which you added the nodes. Just print `g.vs.indices` if you want to check the node order.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is how to estimate the modularity `Q` using `louvain` algorithm in `igraph`.

**Important**: If you have weighted adjacency matrices, DO NOT FORGET the `weights=graph.es['weight']` argument in the below functions!

```
import numpy as np
from igraph import *

W = np.random.rand(10,10)
np.fill_diagonal(W,0.0)

graph = Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(W.tolist(), mode=ADJ_UNDIRECTED, attr="weight", loops=False)

louvain_partition = graph.community_multilevel(weights=graph.es['weight'], return_levels=False)

modularity1 = graph.modularity(louvain_partition, weights=graph.es['weight'])

print("The modularity Q based on igraph is {}".format(modularity1))

The modularity Q based on igraph is 0.02543865641866777
```